# How to change the background of a text field when it is selected?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in which I wanted to change the background image of the text field only when it is selected. Then if it is unselected change back to the previous image ?can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Does selected mean begin editing or something else?

Comment: begin editting untill focus is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In didBeginEditing Method add this code    myTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedimg.png"]; and on didEndEditing method add the deselected image to the textfield.